# Bootstrap 4 - Open modal A; Close Modal A; Open Modal B - A not closing

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I have jobs site. User fills out a form and selects CV (resume) file from PC, hits the Send button. This calls a ajaxSubmit() function which does local validation (removed from the code below) and if OK, does an AJAX file upload. The server side does further validation and returns SUCCESS or ERROR (plus error text) in JSON.

When the user hits the Send button I open a modal #apply_working_modal, which just shows a spinner icon. On ajax.done, I close #apply_working_modal, and if there were errors, put them on the body of modal #apply_errors_modal and open it.

The first time I try it, with an error on purpose, it works as described. If I try it again, with the error still in place, #apply_working_modal shows and will not close until I manually click the X or away from it.

It seems to be some timing issue because when you re-submit after an error, the CV file is already on the server so the JSON comes back very fast. In fact, If I throttle the network just a bit I can make it work.

I have tried variations of waiting on modal events, and also setTimeout() to delay opening of #apply_errors_modal

```
function ajaxSubmit(whichForm){

    $("#apply_working_modal").modal("show"); 
    console.log('showing apply_working_modal');

    var applyRequest =$.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        etc: etc
    });


    applyRequest.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {

        console.log(data);

        $("#apply_working_modal").modal("hide");

        console.log("hiding #apply_working_modal ");

        if (data.STATUS =='SUCCESS') {
            // validation OK at server
        }
        else {// validation error at server

            $('#apply_working_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $("#apply_errors_modal_body").html(data.ErrorText); 
                $("#apply_errors_modal").modal("show");
                console.log("on hidden of #apply_working_modal");
            })
        }               
    });

}
```

This is the output of the console for good/bad tests:

```
//Expected behaviour


15:58:45.981 myscript.js:179 showing apply_working_modal

// 10 seconds pass while server uploads file and returns errors in JSON
15:58:56.696 myscript.js:206 {STATUS: "ERROR", ErrorText: "* The Comments are too short."}
15:58:56.700 myscript.js:217 hiding #apply_working_modal 
15:58:56.998 myscript.js:236 on hidden of #apply_working_modal


// Problem behaviour

15:59:26.704 myscript.js:179 showing apply_working_modal
15:59:26.723 myscript.js:206 {STATUS: "ERROR", ErrorText: "* The Comments are too short."}
15:59:26.724 myscript.js:217 hiding #apply_working_modal 


// #apply_working_modal never gets hidden, have to manually close it
// manual dismiss of modal after waitinf 13 secs ....


15:59:38.525 myscript.js:236 on hidden of #apply_working_modal
15:59:38.526 myscript.js:236 on hidden of #apply_working_modal


// error modal shown but logged many times?
```

The HTML:

```
 <!-- apply working (spinner while sending cv) -->
  <div id="apply_working_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header"> 
          <h4  class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-hourglass-end"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> Sending your CV</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



 <!-- apply errors modal-->
  <div id="apply_errors_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">

       <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 style='color:#cc0000;' class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> There were errors!</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div id="apply_errors_modal_body" class="modal-body">
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button" style="float:left;" class="btn btn-outline-info">Cancel</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update based on answer/comments below.**

For the sake of clarity while posting the question I simplified the ajax request as I did not think it was the cause - in my code  I used 'etc:etc' as an ajax parameter, this was to indicate I simplified the code. I am indeed using cache:false. Full call below (postUrl is set earlier in code):

```
var applyRequest =$.ajax({
    url: postUrl,
    data: postData,
    type: "POST",
    xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandler, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
        }
        return myXhr;
    },

    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data (reqd for use with FormData)
    contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    dataType: "json"
    });
```

Comment: Just an idea, but I had a similar problem. In my case, disabling the `ajax` cache worked. Have you tried to set `cache: false;` in your ajax request?

Comment: how is `ajaxSubmit` called?

Comment: Added code to show I am using cache: false;. And, ajaxSubmit  called via on click of submit button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about the timing, where the modal will *not* be hidden if the backdrop's animation hasn't completed yet. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/javascript/#asynchronous-functions-and-transitions

> ### Asynchronous methods and transitions
>
> All API methods are **asynchronous** and start a **transition**. They
>   return to the caller as soon as the transition is started but **before
>   it ends**. In addition, a method call on a **transitioning component
>   will be ignored**.

— The above quote was taken from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events

*(Updated answer — I removed the `cache: false` stuff.)*

So try *hiding the modal* like this:

```
// Wait for the modal to be made fully visible, where CSS transitions have completed.
$('#apply_working_modal').one('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).modal("hide");
});
```

[See the description of the **`shown.bs.modal`** for more information.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events)

Or use `setTimeout()` like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#apply_working_modal').modal("hide");
}, 1000);
```

---

*(Updated again)* The above (`shown.bs.modal`) works, but in my tests, only if `cache` is `true`. Most likely because the `shown.bs.modal` has already been triggered before the `.done()` is triggered. So try doing it this way:

*(Another update)* Sorry, I myself forgot to use the `.one()`.. and secondly, I combined this with the `setTimeout()` method so that the modal hiding isn't too soon..

*(Aug 15<sup>th</sup> 2018)* I added the missing piece — `$("#apply_working_modal").modal("show");` (just in this answer; thanks @[KevinSol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602088/kevinsol) for pointing it out!).

```
function ajaxSubmit(whichForm){

    var modal_shown = false;
    $('#apply_working_modal').one('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        modal_shown = true;
    });

    $("#apply_working_modal").modal("show");

    ...

    applyRequest.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {

        ...

        // If the modal has been *fully* visible, simply hides it.
        if (modal_shown) {
            $('#apply_working_modal').modal("hide");
        // Else, wait until it's fully visible, and then hides it.
        } else {
            $('#apply_working_modal').one('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                // Wait a few ms before we hide the modal.
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#apply_working_modal').modal("hide");
                }, 100);

                modal_shown = true;
            });
        }

        ...
    });

}
```

And here's <strike>a</strike> **the updated [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBEOyb?editors=1010#0)** for the `shown.bs.modal` event, and [another demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpOGNg?editors=1010#0) for the `setTimeout()` method.

### Additional Note

Here you should use `.one()` instead of the `.on()`:

```
//$('#apply_working_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal' // before
$('#apply_working_modal').one('hidden.bs.modal'  // correct
```

to prevent the event handler from being triggered multiple times:

[image]

Comment: Re cache: false , see my update in the question, I am using that. Will try your answer soon,  about to have a meeting.

Comment: Sure, take your time. I've updated the answer, though.

Comment: Sally CJ thanks for that, it seems to work (version without timeout) perfectly on Chrome, but on Edge and iOS the wait modal seems to close too soon for a successful application. Very tight for time to play with it today, and may not be back till Monday, so have accepted your answer in case the bounty expires! Thanks you for all the work and demos!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. =) I've updated the answer/code and also tested the [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBEOyb?editors=1010#0) on Edge, and so far so good with the `setTimeout()` addition. But sorry, I'm not able to test on iOS..

Comment: Tested on iOS tablet, OSX Mac and Android tablet plus Edge, IE11, Chrome, Opra and FireFox Win 10 - all working, many thanks!  I think this " In addition, a method call on a transitioning component will be ignored." was key to my issues. I must have missed that in the docs. Never knew about .one and yes I did see the issue of multiple calls as you described. Great answer!

Comment: In your answer here you should show $("#apply_working_modal").modal("show");  just after setting modal_shown (before your ...). You have is in the demo but just to be clear for anyone just looking at the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, and sorry about the missing piece there! :)